# Cannot compile Open CV on Ubuntu 18.04 because of jasper.h not found

Tags: opencv, compiler-errors, compilation, ubuntu-18.04, jasper-plugin

I am trying to compile Opencv on Ubuntu 18.04. I installed many dependencies packages but when I run `make` I get the error:

```
grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp:59:10: fatal error: jasper/jasper.h: No such file or directory
 #include <jasper/jasper.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

I had already `jasper` installed and installed `libjasperreports-java`. However the file `jasper.h` cannot still be found in my system. Is there any library I can install with `apt install` to get that file? Or am I missing any other library?

**EDIT 1**

I tried also downloading the opencv_contrib to install  extra moduels of openCV but first of all `jaspar` is not present and secondly setting the build with

```
cmake -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=./ -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=../opencv_contrib/modules ../openCV
```

returns the error:

```
Make Error at cmake/OpenCVModule.cmake:352 (message):
Duplicated modules NAMES has been found
```

while CMakeError.log contains many errors of the type:

```
Build output check failed:
Regex: 'command line option .* is valid for .* but not for C\+\+'
Output line: 'cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++'
```

Comment: I just wanted to suggest using CMake first if you didn't to disable some dependencies, because it's often a pain to have them all and build the complete openCV if you're not gonna use 99% of those. IDK if jasper is optional dependency or not.

Comment: jasper is not even present among extra_modules

Comment: Well, I use CMake on windows and it does give me an option to compile openCV without JasPer support. For me it's dowloaded during CMake configuration into /sources/3rdparty/libjasper and built together with openCV. Just checked CMakeLists.txt and it's under `Optional 3rd Party Components`, look for `OCV_OPTION(WITH_JASPER         "Include JPEG2K support"                      ON   IF (NOT IOS) )` line. Alternatively you might be able to force enable BUILD_JASPER option so cmake downloads it and builds from sources. It's enabled by default on Windows.

Comment: I did a clean build moving creating a new build destination folder inside the downloaded opencv. IN this way it worked and can find the jasper files that as you said were in 3parties while I was expecting them in the git project opencv_contrib. I do not know though if some files were corrupted or it is a real path problem but now it compiled.